# Using nested query error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hey guys i have tried a mysql nested query which is like

```
SELECT test.babe,test.some
FROM (
SELECT  'password' AS babe

) test
```

it work fine

But when i have tried

```
SELECT babe,some
FROM (
SELECT  'password' AS babe
 SELECT 'username' AS some
) test
```

It throws error like

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 'username' AS some ) test' at line 5
```

Am new to mysql.Hope you guys can help me ..!!

Comment: If you are this new to SQL, you will find that reading a book or a tutorial is a more efficient way of learning it than asking questions on StackOverflow. Try http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it as

```
SELECT babe, some
    FROM (
    SELECT 'password' AS babe, 'username' AS some
    ) test
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i add values inside it ??

Comment: when i have tried 
INSERT INTO test ( babe,some )
                       VALUES
                       ( 'sdada','adasd' ); it throws syntax error

Comment: @honeysingh its better to create a table and then insert in to your table and select for your needs

Comment: can we add like that ??

Comment: @honeysingh Also if you have another question then ask a new one with all the brief regarding your problem,and for the above question here is the hint google mysql union query